# Using AWS for HIPAA compliance, how to avoid polling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was looking at this article here:
https://aws.amazon.com/health/healthcare-compliance/hipaa/

Here is the important image:

[image]

My question is - in the article it says that EC2 will poll SQS to see if there is new data - my question is - is there a way for SQS to notify EC2 of new items in the SQS queue so that EC2 servers don't need to poll the queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly is the problem you're having? Does HIPPA prohibit polling?

[SQS Long Polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html) means it really just sits there waiting for a message to arrive, up to 20 seconds.

To answer your question, I'm not aware of any push mechanism in SQS. You can connect SQS and SNS, though without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve I don't know if it would help. SNS can [call http(s) endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html), which might work for you, but I can't immediately find a way to have SQS messages go onto SNS - it might be that you have to use Lambda for that.

You can also have [SQS call a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html), which can then either do what you need directly or call into a web service on the EC2 instance.

Comment: I think there's a common misconception of what "polling" means in the context of SQS.  Long polls over HTTPS is *how the channel is established and maintained over which SQS pushes messages* to the consumer as they arrive.  It's an implementation detail that gives the wrong impression.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that's another way of putting it. Another way would be to say EC2 is connected to SQS and will get sent any new SQS messages immediately.

Comment: @Tim thanks can you link to docs that describe SQS messages being pushed to EC2 instead of being pulled?

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional information